# combination 2 SQL table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect***;

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM componnets LEFT JOIN fill ON componnets.id=fill.Uid') or die(mysqli_error(mysqli));
$resultCOM = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM componnets') or die(mysqli_error(mysqli));

while ($rowCOM = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCOM)) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='compo' value='".$rowCOM['compon']."'>".$rowCOM['compon']."";
    echo "<select name='fill'>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
        echo "<option value='".$row['num']."'>".$row['num']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

the question is this, i need to combine between 2 sql.
the result i need is that:

```html
<input type='hidden' name='compo' value='decod'>decod
<select name='fill'><option value='100'>100</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='compo' value='rg5.9'>rg5.9
<select name='fill'><option value='100'>100</option>
<select name='fill'><option value='100'>200</option>
<select name='fill'><option value='100'>300</option>
</select>
```

i try all combins and nothing..

the output in now is like this

```html
<input type='hidden' name='compo' value='decod'>decod
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='compo' value='rg5.9'>rg5.9
<select name='fill'><option value='100'>100</option>
<select name='fill'><option value='100'>300</option>
</select>
```

the mysql is bulld like this

```
fill - num uid 
       100   3
       300   1

componnets - id  compon
             1    decod
             2    rg59
             3    rg6
```

thx for help.

Comment: `mysqli_error(mysqli)` if that's your real code, it's failing and is missing a `$` for it `mysqli_error($mysqli)` should there be an error.

Comment: your query is generating duplicates, seeing that you also have 2x hidden inputs bearing the same name attributes `name='compo'` and also for `<select name='fill'>`.

Comment: its not order it by uid to the id its not fall. also the hidden its for save THE subject to doc

Comment: Do you want in your select only the values from `fill` related to the respective `id` in `componnets`? Your desired result does not match your sample data.

Comment: i try everthing but yes this what i need..